# Trouble in destroying session

Tags: php

I am having trouble in destroying session when user logout of its account. After logging out when i browse any page which is restricted to user not to access before login i can access that but if i close my browser after logging out and then try to access the page i cant. Please solve my problem so that user cannot access the pages after logging out even he/she has not closed the browser. Here's my code of logging out and destroying session.

```
     <?php
     // Initialize the session.
     // If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
      if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
      session_start();

      // Unset all of the session variables.
          $_SESSION = array();
          $_SESSION["Alogin"] = "";

      // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session 
          cookie.
     // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
      if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
         $params = session_get_cookie_params();
         setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
         $params["path"], $params["domain"],
         $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
        );
      }

     // Finally, destroy the session.
      session_destroy();
      }
     ?>
```

Comment: Can you give an example how you check if a user can acces a page?

Comment: @Cid when user logins to his/her account i set a session variable Alogin to Ok and on the restricted pages i check whether that variable is set or not

Comment: `session_start()` at the top, and use `unset($_SESSION['Alogin'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session `session_start()` must be at the top

```
 <?php
 // Initialize the session.
 session_start();
 // If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
  if(isset($_POST['logout'])){


  //What ever you want

  // Finally, destroy the session.

  unset( $_SESSION );
  session_destroy();

  //redirect to loginpage
  header('Location:../login.php');
  exit;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Done it worked perfectly. There is one more question how can i preserve value of one variable even if the session is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your `session_start ();` outside the if statement and
2. check with `print_r ($_POST);` if you send `$_POST['logout']`